# JavaScript key hooking issue on Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, opera

I'm doing a video interface web with HTML5 and JavaScript.

I'm having problems with JavaScript because I need to control the video with keys so when someone press a key from the keyboard, for example 'P', the video will be on 'Play' or 'Pause'.
**The problem is that it's not working on Chrome and Opera but does on Firefox.**

The excerpts below are parts of the total code:

The HTML:

```
<video width="775" id="player" preload controls timeupdate="timeupdate()"  onclick="repro()" onMouseOver="mostrarControles()" onMouseOut="ocultarControles()">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video.webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm" />
    TU NAVEGADOR NO SOPORTA VIDEO EN HTML5.
</video>
<div id="controls" onMouseOut="ocultarControles()" onMouseOver="mostrarControles()" >
    <!-- Buttons of control-->
</div>
```

`Java.JS` - Function where I have problems on Chrome and Opera:

```
document.getElementById("controls").addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
    controlTeclado(event);
    //alert("OK");
}, true);
```

I have detected that Chrome and Opera don't access inside the `.addEventListener()` and I don't know why, any idea?

`ProgressBar.JS:`

```
function controlTeclado(evento) {
    mostrarControles(); // show controls on the web page
    if (evento.keyCode==80) {
        alert(" Key: "+evento.keyCode);
        repro(); //play video
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in the console? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Javascript works fine on chrome and opera, so I edited your title.

Comment: @ColBeseder, no error message on the console, only are not taking the keys.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` elements do not receive key events by default. Only focusable elements such as form inputs and contenteditable elements do. To make a regular `<div>` able to fire key events, assign it a `tabIndex` (a value of zero means that the element is in the regular tab order):

```
<div id="controls" tabindex="0"
        onMouseOut="ocultarControles()" onMouseOver="mostrarControles()">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried with that option and it is not working properly on Chrome and Firefox neither. I have another call to focus the key on the player. 
'document.getElementById("player").addEventListener('focus',function(event) {
   controlTeclado(event);
  }, true); '

Comment: I have added that option on <video> and it looks fine, let me do some test and i will return! Thanks guys!!!!!